# Proper way to Initialize C++ struct that has other structs and array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, initialization

I have the following code and I need to initialize the `XYZ` struct. Please give me a way to do this.

```
struct Demo
{
    int abc[10];
    int reply_port;
};

struct XYZ 
{
    struct Demo dem[10];
    int x;
    int y;
    struct Demo a;
    struct Demo b;
    struct Demo c;
} arr[100];
```

`Demo1` is another `struct` that is available in other file. Please tell me an efficient way in how this struct `XYZ` can be initialized.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to initialize it to?  All 0s?

Comment: How do you want to initialize the structs? There are different kinds of initialization.

Comment: If you ask a question about C++, don't tag C. The modern languages can be *very* different.

Comment: Can you use c++11 features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why do you want to do it this way, but if you insist:

```
  struct XYZ myXYZ = { 
    {   
      // dem[10]
      {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},80},
      {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},80},
      {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},80},
      {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},80},
      {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},80},
      {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},80},
      {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},80},
      {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},80},
      {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},80},
      {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},80}
    },  
    10, // x
    20, // y
    {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},80}, // a
    {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},80}, // b
    {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},80}  // c
  };
```

I would think of designing it differently, but I don't know what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I wonder why magic numbers from 1 to 10 and then 80 are of use, but the author of the question seems not to be interested in discourse

Comment: The numbers are just an example. Why 80? In his structure he has reply_port in that position in the struct, and 80 is one of the most widely used ports today on the Internet :), hence I chose it as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Init to all 0's

```
XYZ xyz = {};
```

No init: http://ideone.com/wE7MCF → undefined behavior

Init: http://ideone.com/BT81PH → all 0s

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you use class? Further in the class you may define a parameterized constructor.

Or do you want to do it with structures only?

Comment: In this context, `class` and `struct` make no difference in C++.

Comment: Going by the definitions I tend to keep structures responsible only for data items. I restrain myself from using classes till its not entirely necessary.

Comment: Right, but both things are the same in C++. You can define exactly the same types using either.

Comment: Yes. I have had the experience of that while working on one project when my professor shared the same thing with me. C++ compilers tend to assume structures as classes. There remains no difference but to avoid confusion in other languages I like to keep things clear. :)

Comment: And you can define a constructor for the struct:  Demo() : reply_report(0) { memset(...) }

Comment: It is not about what compilers *tend* to do, it is specified in the C++ standard. It is a part of the language.